# Cambiar ID de una imagen que se encuentra en archivo XML (Android Studio) directamente en codigo Java

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

Tengo un Layout con 3 imagenes, les asigno ID, se llaman Imagen1, Imagen2 e Imagen3, ya teniendo ese Layout, lo mando a llamar repetidas veces en mi Layout Principal de tal manera que queda una tabla de imagenes de 3 por 20, ya teniendo esa tabla de imagenes quiero que al presionar cada imagen se obtenga informacion de esa imagen, pero tengo un problema, solo tengo 3 ID's diferentes, se puede asignar nuevos ID`s cada vez que llamo al Layout con las 3 imagenes?

CODIGO PARA "INFLAR" EL LAYOUT CON LOS 3 IMAGEVIEW

```
 @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private void addChild(String img1, String img2, String img3) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    int id = R.layout.productos;

 RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(id, null, false);

    ImageView Producto1 = (ImageView)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.ImagenProducto1);
    ImageView Producto2 = (ImageView)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.ImagenProducto2);
    ImageView Producto3 = (ImageView)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.ImagenProducto3);


    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(img1)
            .into(Producto1);

    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(img2)
            .into(Producto2);

    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(img3)
            .into(Producto3);


    layout.addView(relativeLayout);


    }
```

CODIGO DEL BUCLE DONDE REPITO EL LLAMADO DEL LAYOUT DE LAS 3 IMAGENES

```
 for (int x=1; x<22; x++)
    {


        addChild(URLVerduras[a],URLVerduras[b],URLVerduras[c]);

        a = a+3;
        b = b+3;
        c = c+3;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso, te recomiendo crear las imagenes por el codigo y no en el layout

```
for (int i = 1;int < 23; i++)
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setId(i);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.tu_imagen);
    //Aqui le das estilo, posicion, etc.
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.ButtonRecalculate);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    relativeLayout.addView(iv, lp);
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias!!!!! Lo pude solucionar con tu ayuda!!!

Comment: me alegro amigo @JesusRomeroG